# How do you view the output of an exception in check_output

Tags: python, output

I have some Python 2.7 code that runs a Windows command.  If the command is successful, it returns the output.  (More specifically, it searches the multiple line output for a search term and then returns the line that has that search term).

If the command fails, it simply returns "Error"

I'd like to modify this code to return the actual error message.  How do I make the "exception" part of my function to return the actual error message that was outputted by the command?

```
def myFunction(machineName):
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output('command ' + machineName)
    for line in output.split('\n'):
        if 'TextToSearchFor' in line:
            return line
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    return "Error"
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Set and get `subprocess.CalledProcessError.message`. This way the message is displayed when the error is not handled as well and it is good programming if there is any chance this Exception will be used by other programmers.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation actually has [an example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) on that: use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` in the call.

It also mentions that subprocess.CalledProcessError has an `output` attribute that contains any output from the process (I'm assuming this is `stdout`, but perhaps also `stderr`, in which case you don't need to set `stderr` in the call itself).

Thus you should be able to use (untested):

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output('command ' + machineName)
    for line in output.split('\n'):
        if 'TextToSearchFor' in line:
            return line
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print subprocess.CalledProcessError.output
    return "Error"
return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exception:

```
def myFunction(machineName):
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output('command ' + machineName)
        for line in output.split('\n'):
            if 'TextToSearchFor' in line:
                return line
    except Exception, e:
        print e
        return "Error"
    return
```

If you are interested in stack trace, you can do this:

```
import trace
```

at except Exception, e: you can add

```
traceback.print_exc()
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware - the exception you are trapping is not the only exception you might expect:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> try:
...     output = subprocess.check_output("nosuch")
... except Exception as e:
...     print str(e)
...
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
>>> e
OSError(2, 'No such file or directory')
>>> type(e)
<type 'exceptions.OSError'>
```

Also note that the interface to your function means that you have to make specific checks for errors, leading to a loss of clarity in your logic, as every call must look like:

```
result = myFunction(someArg):
if result.startswith("error"):
    # handle issue somehow
else:
    # normal logic flow to do something with result
```

It is actually much simpler to handle exceptions at the appropriate point by removing error checking from your function and handling the resulting exceptions at the call. Your code will then look like

```
try:
    # normal logic flow to do something with result
except (tuple, of, exceptions) as e:
    # handle issue somehow
```

Note also that exceptions can be converted to dtrings, which normally gives you any associated error message, as shown in the opening example, so that's the real answer to your question.

If your Python is recent enough you should use the `except ... as name:` format rather than `except ..., name:` because it will migrate to Python 3 without change.